# Integrating 3rd-party forum software to member-based website

Tags: security, web-applications, forums

When using some existing forum software in a larger web-site, how easy is it to:

1)Make your site's login functionality log the user into the forum

2)Make your site's registration functionality create forum login data

I suppose in a way it might be easier to ONLY use the forum's database for maintaining users, but that means trusting it with sensitive data.

I'm planning an integration between an existing bespoke desktop app and a new bespoke web-site which should include forums. I don't know which forums will be used but I know the new web functionality *won't* be PHP-based. I figure that's not a big deal but I'm wondering if forums typically allow configuration of where they look for login data, to avoid duplicating this data into my DB and the forum DB.

Comment: I'm so glad your actually making the effort to so this! So many sites seem to make you have separate accounts - really frustrating! You might want to contact the dropbox team (www.dropbox.com and http://forums.getdropbox.com) They have done a nice job integrating their accounts with BBpress.

Answer (score 2):

It's usually pretty easy, but it completely depends on the Forum software that you choose.

I've written systems in both PHP and ASP.Net (C#) that integrate with phpBB or vBulletin databases.

The login functionality is the easiest part to implement because the hash is stored in the DB (usually a salt will be too), and you just need to check one field to another and voila you can authenticate!

The registration of users is a little more difficult.

The way I did it was browsing through their source code to find out what SQL commands were necessary during the registration step.

So, depending on the forum software you choose, the difficulty will change, but overall it's not to difficult to make happen.

I would offer you snippets on how to integrate with PHPBB and VB, but since those are both PHP based, you said you weren't going to use them.

Comment: I see no reason I shouldn't use PHP-based forum software, regardless that the new app won't use PHP. It's a pain nearly all the free web software is PHP though.

Answer (score 0):

You are actually looking for a Single Sign On feature, that is integrated in several forum softwares, like [Simple Machines](http://www.forum-software.org/simple-machines-2/review/conclusion-advantages-opinion) and [JForum](http://www.forum-software.org/jforum/review/conclusion-advantages-opinion) for example.